# CSS Contact Form 7 Spacing

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I can't for the life of me figure out the spacing on my form.

As you'll see the checkboxes are all bunched up and look rubbish... can you league of coding legends help?

http://200620.co.uk/

This is the layout...

```
    <div class="wpcf7-wrap">
<div class="col-sm-6">
     [text* your-name placeholder "Name:"]
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
     [text* your-email placeholder "Email:"]
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
     [select* menu-383 placeholder "Are you coming?" "I'm there" "No, sorry"]
  </div>  

<div class="col-sm-6">
     [select* menu-384 placeholder "Transport there & back?" "There" "Back" "Both"]
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
     [text your-text-1 placeholder "Dietary Requirements:"]
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-6">What do you drink?
[checkbox checkbox-133 label_first use_label_element "Gin" "Vodka" "Whiskey" "Rum" "Prosecco" "Soft Drinks"]
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
     [text your-text-3 placeholder "What do you want to hear?"]
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
     [textarea your-text-4 placeholder "Any Special Message for us?"]
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 wpcf7-button-wrap">
    [submit "RSVP Baby"]
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this puts you on the right track.  I would move your checkboxes to after the other 2x2 columns so that it's all the way across.  Also.. Wrap the whole thing in a div.  Be careful not to add extra line breaks on your form, as Contact Form 7 uses the "Auto-P" function.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
/*this should make the row stand on it's own*/
.checkbox-row {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 .5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpcf7-wrap">
    <div class="col-sm-6"> [text* your-name placeholder "Name:"] </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> [text* your-email placeholder "Email:"] </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> [select* menu-383 placeholder "Are you coming?" "I'm there" "No, sorry"] </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> [select* menu-384 placeholder "Transport there & back?" "There" "Back" "Both"] </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> [text your-text-1 placeholder "Dietary Requirements:"] </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> [text your-text-3 placeholder "What do you want to hear?"] </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 checkbox-row"><div>What do you drink? [checkbox checkbox-133 label_first use_label_element "Gin" "Vodka" "Whiskey" "Rum" "Prosecco" "Soft Drinks"]</div></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"> [textarea your-text-4 placeholder "Any Special Message for us?"] </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 wpcf7-button-wrap"> [submit "RSVP Baby"] </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked an absolute treat - Just now not playing ball responsively - I have tried display:block but she's not wanting to play either, can you help a brother out on this one?

Comment: I would do something like this. `@media(max-width: 767px){.checkbox-row .wpcf7-list-item{display: block;}} `  I think you should be able to style the rest from that?  Please don't forget to accept the answer also :)

Comment: let me know if you get stuck.

Answer (score -1):

Just add below CSS code. Hope this help you.

```
.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-checkbox{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Check it working good can  you try "body .wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox{}"

Comment: Added one, added both still no movement on it...

.wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body .wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox{}

It's going in the Addional CSS section on wordpress

Comment: sorry you can replace ".wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox"  to ".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-checkbox"